# Checkout current branch in bare repo to worktree

Tags: git

I'm doing a local test where I have:

- repo 1
- bare repo
- work-tree folder

I pushed some changes to the bare repo. Now I want to manually deploy it to the work tree.

I go into the bare repo, where master is checked out, and I try to checkout master and setting the worktree to the worktree folder:

```
set WT=../myworktree                     //<-- create env variable on windows
git --work-tree=%WT% checkout -f master
```

But the result is: `'Already on 'master'`, and no changes are made to the worktree files.

I recognize it from when you push to a remote bare repo where you have a post-receive hook, it also says "Already on master" but it does deploy the files to the worktree (due to the `-f` (force) flag I think)

So how can I checkout the same branch again to a worktree so that it is "refreshed" with new content?

By the way, if I do `git worktree list` in the bare repo , it points to the bare repo and says `(bare)`, I guess that's as it should be.

**Edit**

The worktree folder originally had a .git directory, but I removed it - is that the problem? I was thinking that I only needed the bare repo and no repo inside the worktree?

**Edit - issue went away, must have been some mistake(?)**

This might not have been an issue because it started working now, so maybe it was some mistake I did.

I made a new "work-tree folder"  (cloned from the bare repo, removed the remote and .git folder). Then tried the command again but first adding a remote url pointing to the "work-tree", then pushed a change from "repo 1" to the bare repo. Now in the bare repo, when I did `git --work-tree=%WT% checkout -f master` , it says `'Already on 'master'`, but the files were updated in the work tree folder. So I thought it was because of the remote url, but after removing that (`git remote remove origin`) the checkout command still worked.

So I must have made some mistake originally (not sure what it was).

(It also doesn't matter how the worktree is created, because I created a new worktree folder again and manually adding some random files, and the command still works, updating the files)

Comment: Bare repos don't have a worktree. What you call here worktree might exist on the server, but is not known as such to your bare repo. If you *do* need a worktree, what's the point of a bare repo? (The question sounds like "How do I locate the wire of my wireless phone?")

Comment: @Romain The idea came up when I cloned a local repo to another local repo. I made some changes, but couldn't push, since the original repo has a checked out worktree.
I was mainly using them to try out git stuff, so I need to be able to push and pull to a common repo. The bare repo makes it possible I guess.

Comment: If I were to use a bare repo locally, I would push and pull to/from it, but not try to give it an actual worktree. To get another sandbox to work in, I'd just clone the bare repo again somewhere else, basically treating the bare repo as if it was on a remote server.

Comment: In any case, your `git --work-tree=%WT% checkout -f master` command worked fine for me as long as the directory `%WT%` already existed. I only got the message `Already on 'master'` when that was indeed the case.

Comment: But if you really want a worktree off of your bare repo, I think the command to run is `git worktree add %WT% master`, that will actually create a worktree attached to your bare repo.

Comment: Note that bare clones may have traps for the unwary (e.g., the default fetch refspec is empty!). It's usually wise to reserve bare clones for the singular purpose for which they were originally made: to exist as a place to *clone from*, on a server, that can be `git push`-ed *to* later. (They may also have certain uses as reference clones.)

Answer (score 2):

##### Use `git worktree add`

If you want to create worktrees attached to a bare repo, you need to use the `git worktree add` command, just like you would from a regular sandbox.

```
git worktree add <pathtoworktree> master
```

then your can do your Git operations in either the worktree or in the bare repo.

E.g.:

```
cd bare-repo
git --work-tree=<pathtoworktree> status
```

is equivalent to:

```
cd <pathtoworktree>
git status
```

and ditto for all other Git operations like checkout, commit and whatnot.

And then `git worktree list` will show both the bare repo path with `(bare)` and the worktree path with its current checkout commit and branch.

##### Alternative - just clone it

You can also treat the bare repo as if it was on a remote server:

```
cd sandboxes
git clone <path-to-bare-repo>
```

and that will create a new sandbox you can use in a normal way, which will push and pull to/from your bare repo.

##### Personal opinion

While this worktrees work, I would actually just treat a local bare repo as a remote and clone it.

Using worktrees is more efficient because they share the Git folder contents, but I personally find it more confusing when I'm looking at my collection of sandboxes if some are connected to others. I like being able to wipe out any sandbox without affecting any other sandbox, and worktrees would mean I'd have to be mindful of potential connections when I did that.

I'd rather just have duplicate copies, unless the repo was very large and I needed the optimization that worktrees provide. (E.g., if I worked on the Linux kernel, yes, I'd be using worktrees!)

Comment: If adding a worktree to the bare repo , that branch is seems to be treated as non bare, because if I push something from "repo 1" it says "refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master. By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository is denied"

Comment: About cloning: Yes Repo 1 was created by cloning the Bare repo, so it is treated as a remote. The strange thing now is that my command suddenly works, so I'll add that info, so the issue seems solved by itself somehow. But thanks for the info anyway.